# how to execute unix commands within nzsql?

Tags: scripting, teradata, unix, netezza

I'm converting a script from Teradata to Netezza, and I'm stuck at the portion where BTEQ uses the functionality of the OS to check if a file contains any data. If it does, it is deleted. I want to perform the same function in `nzsql`.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.gsg.doc/c_getstrt_nzsql_slash_cmds.html) for `nzsql` states that to shell-out you just have to use blackslash pling, followed by the command:

```
\! command
```

If you need to know how to test for file size in a shell script, you can use something similar to:

```
if [[ -f $file ]] && [[ -s $file ]]; then 
  echo "File exists and is greater than 0 bytes" ; 
  rm -f $file
fi
```

`-f` checks that it exists, `-s` checks if it's greater than 0 bytes.